# How to copy artifacts generated by a build (php web app) to a directory on the same server?

Tags: php, build, teamcity, build-process, teamcity-9.0

We're using TeamCity 9 on Ubunutu system.
I want to copy the the artifacts published in the build to a directory (defined in Apache config as virtual directory) so that our application would get deployed.

Currently, our artifacts are being published in 
`root/.BuildServer/system/artifacts/repo_name/build_name/some_number/some_hash_value` directory.

I want to copy it to, let's say, `\home\ubuntu\repo_name` directory.

How should I do it?

Comment: Is some_number and some_hash_value available during the build?

Comment: @Mattias : No! some_number is being incremented by 2 after every build.

Comment: @Mattias : I solved the problem by doing this.
`cp -R -f %teamcity.build.workingDir% /home/ubuntu/repo_name`
It is now creating or copying into a directory with name `some_hash_value` in the `repo_name` folder. The `some_hash_value` is not changing, irrespective of build numbers (or builds) , so far, so good.
Is this a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways

1. > `cp -R -f %teamcity.build.workingDir%/* /home/ubuntu/repo_name/`
2. Create a vcs checkout rule in your build target of the form `.+:=>custom_name`.This checks out VCS contents into a directory named `custom_name`.Then you can copy it using this command

> `cp -R -f %teamcity.build.workingDir%/custom_name /home/ubuntu/repo_name/`

In case you only want to copy the artefacts, you can generate all your artefacts in one sub-directory under the build directory and copy files from that direcotry to the target directory

Comment: Hi @Biswajit_86 : Is this the right way to do the thing?
I mean, this will copy the working directory, not the artifacts!!

Answer (score 0):

How about setting artifact path explicitly in the build configuration? You can read more here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths